# Seasonal data forecasting issues

Tags: time-series, spss, arima

I have a seasonally decomposed data set. The data set has strong seasonality. 
Now I am trying to fit the 'seasonal part' of dataset into ARIMA model and tried to forecast (with SPSS).

The problem is, I get exactly same values in forecasts as that of actual values. So, MAPE is coming to be 0.000

Is this obvious to happen or am I doing something wrong?

P.S.
The data set is here: http://mihirsathe.com/mihir/STI/STI/drugs/index.html

Comment: Have you predicted the last values of response variable for $t$ from 228 to 233? What are your predicted values? If you take in-sample accuracy statistics your residuals are quite large, note that random is multiplicative part as well as seasonal. So the additive residuals could be taken straightforward as actuals - fitted. So as compared to actuals your fit won't give you 0 in sample MAPE. Thus I guess you are doing something wrong. What are you actually doing?

Comment: Last predicted values are : 
0.99
0.95
1.03
0.99
1.02

Comment: @Dmitrij Celov Sir, I think there is some misunderstanding. I am trying to predict the seasonal part. Not the actual series.

Comment: And when I tried to do exactly same forecasting with R language, it gave me following error:
`Error in arima(diff(series), order = c(1, 0, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(1, : non-stationary seasonal AR part from CSS`

Comment: for the seasonal predictions you may use the latest updates in `forecast` library http://www.r-bloggers.com/major-changes-to-the-forecast-package/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RBloggers+%28R+bloggers%29 many thanks to @Rob J. Hyndman as always. And try the improved `auto.arima` Your error says you have a unit root problem, seasonal differencing will help hear (strong seasonal part equivalent to seasonal unit root). And also a good non-parametric forecast could be done by `stlf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seasonal factors are a set of constants repeating every 12 periods thus it is a deterministic series and then can't be modeled that's why the other responders are getting error messages. If you want to predict the seasonal component just extend the seasonal factors into the future . For example the sf of 227 = the seasonal factor for 215 = seasonal factor for 203 etc. thus the sf for 239 would the df for for 227 .

Comment: (+1) that's a good note regarding SPSS forecasting the constants, no surprise that then you have MAPE $0$.

Comment: On the other hand if the author really did correct SARIMA model without the exogenously defined constant factors, the seasonal part will be slightly (due to strong autocorrelation) time varying. The seasonal decomposition as presented in raw data file, I guess, is not the output from SARIMA fit.

Comment: Oh my god I didn't realize those values are periodic with 12. Thank you so much sir... u have solved another problem for me...

Answer (score 2):

The model ( somewhat archaic generated a "random component" ) that is being imposed by the user is a multiplicative Holt-Winters model. Assuming a model often leads to errors that are non-random and therefore have structure thus the reported "random component" might be indeed non-random. A straightforward analysis leads to a plot of the "random component" reported by the OP[image] and the ACF of same [image] . Analyzing this stream of numbers yields an equation of[image] with a STRONG SEASONAL STRUCTURE and a subsequent ACF [image] with a time series plot of a truly random set of residuals.[image] . The point is both sophisticated and un-sophisticated users are controlled by their available software and their understanding of time series methods.! note that the "random component" reported by the user reflects strong seasonal structure is a modern-day example of the Slutsky Effect which notes that structure can be injected by incorrect filtering.

Comment: For transparency reasons, I should note that I am using software that I have been involved with as a developer. Most available software will duplicate the findings that I have presented here.

Answer (score 0):

Split your data into a training and test set.  The training set should come before the test set.  Ideally, the test should be a full seasonal cycle or more.  Compare you forecasts for the test set to the actuals for the test set.